# find nth prime in java with low time complexity

Tags: java, primes

I'm trying to find a low time complexity solution for finding nth prime.
However there's some method problems I'm quite confused.
Also I want to know is mine has a low time complexity or can it be better?

I've tried two different ways to find the prime while the first one is way too slow, so i changed another one. But the boolean method has some problem which i have no idea.

```
public static int FInd_NthPrime(int n){
        int num=0,j,c=2;
        while (true) {
            if(isPrime(c)){
                num = num+1;
            }
            c = c+1;
            break;
        }
        return c; // the error happened
}

public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
    for (int i = 2; i < Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}


public static void print_nth_prime(int num){
    int result = FInd_NthPrime(num);
    System.out.print(num +" "+result);
}
```

I expect anyone tell me the mistake in boolean method and is there any better way to make low time complexity for finding the nth prime。

Comment: Throw it all away and use the Sieve of Eratosthenes to construct a primes table, then return the `n`th element, remembering about 0-based indexing. An `isPrime()` method should basically never be written. How large the table should be is left as an exercise for the reader ;-)

Comment: Thanks! Just check the Sieve of Eratosthenes and it helps me a lot! I'm still learning the data structure and algorithm so most of my work will be throw away anyway. lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to test odd integers and special case "2".

And when doing the `isPrime` test, just do the modulo check against existing primes already discovered.

```
public static int FInd_NthPrime(int n){

    int val = 3;    // first odd number greater than 2
    int result = 0;

    if (n <= 1) {
        return 2;  // special case for 2, the only even prime
    }

    // build up a Hash table of all discovered primes so far
    ArrayList<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    primes.add(2);

    while (n > 1) {
        if (isPrime(val, primes)) {
            n--;
            result = val;
        }
        val += 2;  // increment to the next odd integer
    }
    return result;
}

public static boolean isPrime(int n, ArrayList<Integer> primes) {

    if (n == 2) {
        return true;
    }

    int stop = (int)Math.sqrt(n);

    for (int divisor : primes) {
        if ((n % divisor) == 0)  {
            return false;
        }
        if (divisor > stop) {
            break;
        }
    }

    //System.out.format("Added %d to prime list\n", n);
    primes.add(n);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: thanks! it helps me a lot! The code work while the time complexity is a little bit larger than I thought. it took serval minutes to compute 1000001th prime lol. But I did help me to understand the problem that i made.

Comment: @GawainGan - I apologize.  I gave you an inefficient solution.  The use of a HashTable is a terrible idea because it will deliberately enumerate in a random order instead of checking the lowest primes first, which will have the highest probability of elimination.  Replace with an ArrayList.  Further, checking from `divisor > sqrt(n)` also makes it more efficient.  This reduces the running time from a few minutes to just a couple of seconds to compute the 1000001th prime.  Again, sorry about that.  Please reference the updated code in my answer.